# algorithm to Find connected components in a graph and to which connected components each node does it belong

Tags: graph, graph-theory, undirected-graph

I have an undirected graph and looking for (efficient) algorithm that determine how many connected components there is in the and for every node it could tell in which connected components it locate.

I think it might be the Depth-First Search but not sure about it.

Comment: Given a starting node, any kind of search (depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, etc) will give you the list of all other nodes that are in the same connected component as that node.

Comment: Thus one trivial algorithm is as follow: 1) Pick a starting node. 2) Perform a search starting from that node to collect all nodes in the same connected component. 3) Pick a new starting node among the nodes that haven't been explored yet, and start again, and again, until there are no remaining nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, we have the next disconnected graph:

[image]

I can offer the solution of your problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=10;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
vector<int> graph[maximumSize];
vector<vector<int>> components;
int vertices, edges;
void showContentVector1D(vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void showContentVector2D(vector<vector<int>>& input)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        ++count;
        cout<<count<<": ";
        for(int j=0; j<input[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout<<input[i][j]<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
void createGraph()
{
    cin>>vertices>>edges;
    int vertex0, vertex1;
    for(int edge=1; edge<=edges; ++edge)
    {
        cin>>vertex0>>vertex1;
        graph[vertex0].push_back(vertex1);
        graph[vertex1].push_back(vertex0);
    }
    return;
}
void depthFirstSearch(int currentVertex, int previousVertex, vector<int>& graphVertices)
{
    if(visited[currentVertex]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[currentVertex]=1;
    graphVertices.push_back(currentVertex);
    for(int nextVertex : graph[currentVertex])
    {
        if(nextVertex==previousVertex)
        {
            continue;
        }
        depthFirstSearch(nextVertex, currentVertex, graphVertices);
        continue;
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    createGraph();
    vector<int> graphVertices;
    int quantityOfComponents=0;
    for(int vertex=0; vertex<vertices; ++vertex)
    {
        if(visited[vertex]==0)
        {
            ++quantityOfComponents;
            depthFirstSearch(vertex, -1, graphVertices);
            components.push_back(graphVertices);
            graphVertices.clear();
        }
    }
    cout<<"components <- "<<endl;
    showContentVector2D(components);
    cout<<endl<<"quantityOfComponents <- "<<quantityOfComponents<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5 4
0 1
0 2
1 2
3 4
```

Output:

```
components <- 
1: 0, 1, 2, 
2: 3, 4, 

quantityOfComponents <- 2
```

If you have the concrete questions, write the corresponding comment.